# how can I select two dates today and tomorrow from calendar of booking website using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[image: Screenshot from the calender]

I have tried to use the below code to detect the checkin button, but I cannot work out how to select the dates as shown in the image above.

```
public class Hotel_Search {

    void search(WebDriver driver) {
        // find destination WebElement des = driver.findElement(By.name("ss"));
        // fill destination des.sendKeys("Ain Sokhna");
        // select checkin button WebElement Checkinhbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div1/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div1/div/button")); Checkinhbutton.click(); //call select date of today method SelectDateOfToday(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div1/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div1/table/thead/tr1/th"))); //find search button WebElement searchbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div1/div[4]/div[2]/button"));
        // searchbutton.click(); }
        // public void SelectDateOfToday(WebElement Calender_Xpath) {

        String today = getCurrentDay();
        List<WebElement> columns = Calender_Xpath.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement cell : columns) {
            //If you want to click 18th Date if (cell.getText().equals("18")) {
            // Select Today's Date
            if (cell.getText().equals(today)) {
                cell.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private String getCurrentDay() {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        String date = dtf.format(localDate);
        return date;

    }
}
```

Comment: Push your code and HTML (or URL). This is not service for writing code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution

```
@Test
public void calendarSelector() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);

    //Define locators in advance (Really should move this stuff into a page object)
    By checkInLocator = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'b-datepicker')][@data-mode='checkin']");
    By calendarLocator = By.cssSelector(".bui-calendar__content");

    //Wait until checkIn element is displayed and then click on it
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(checkInLocator)).click();
    //Wait until calendar is displayed
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(calendarLocator));

    //Work out today and tomorrow
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays(1L);

    //Use selectDate method to click on the relevant dates
    selectDate(driver, today);
    selectDate(driver, tomorrow);
}

private void selectDate(WebDriver driver, LocalDate date) {
    //Looking at the markup the attribute data-date is formatted as an ISO_LOCAL_DATE
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    //Programmatically generate dateLocator based on date passed in
    By dateLocator = By.xpath(String.format("//td[@data-date='%s']", formatter.format(date)));
    //Wait for date element to be visible, then click on it
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dateLocator)).click();
}
```

The select date method would need to be a little more complex if you wanted to search for dates that are not displayed on initial open of the calendar widget, you would need to work out what dates are displayed, compare to your desired date and then click the month navigation buttons appropriately, you don't need that additional functionality for your current scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question, you are trying to interract with https://www.booking.com/. To be able to select dates you can try the following:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class BookingTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
    // not the implementation.
    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");
    // wait until page will load completely
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        (Function<? super WebDriver, Boolean>) webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));

    // open calendar
    // note sometimes the xpath to the clendar button gets changed, therefore is the 'if' statement here
    List<WebElement> openCalButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label= 'Open calendar']"));
    if (openCalButton.size() < 1){
      openCalButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class= 'sb-date-field__icon sb-date-field__icon-btn bk-svg-wrapper calendar-restructure-sb']"));
    }
    openCalButton.get(0).click();

    // store month and year
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US);
    String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
    String year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";
    String monthYear = month_name + " " + year;

    // store day
    String day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "";

    // find date
    WebElement date =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th[contains(.,'"
        + monthYear + "')]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/tbody/tr/td/span[@class = 'c2-day-inner'][contains(.,'"
        + day + "')]")).get(0);
    date.click();

    // this pause is only to prevent to exit the code immediately, if you want to see yhe result before page closes
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i tried the code but i have got this error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<WebElement>" in this line --- WebElement date = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th[contains(.,'" + monthYear + "')]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/tbody/tr/td/span[@class = 'c2-day-inner'][contains(.,'" + day + "')]"))[1];
date.click();

Comment: Hi! i have added an working example, please try it. Note: for this code you need `Java 8`. Please tell me if it's working for you

Comment: So, is your problem with selecting date solved? Does my code work for you?